# Solving a recurrence relation with both decrementing and slicing the element by a constant

Tags: time-complexity

Given:
$$f(1) = 1 \\ f(n) = 4f(n-1) + f(n/3) + f(n/8)$$
(if $n<1$ then it is still 1)
And I need to find $\Theta(f(n))$, can I do this?

$$ \Theta( f(n))  = \Theta(4f(n-1)) + \Theta(f/3)) + \Theta(f(n/8))$$

Then solve each term and get that it is $\Theta(4^n)$ ?

Or it is not possible as we basically have this:

$$ f(n) = 4 (  4f(n-2) + f((n-1)/3) + f((n-1)/8)) + f(n/3) + f(n/8) $$ etc... and by the end we have:

$$ \sum_{m=0}^{n} 4^{m} ( f((n-m)/3) + f((n-m)/8)) $$

But this seems so incorrect because then each term in the sum calls the functions **again** with its value, thus making another sum and another sum..
this is really crazy and I cannot comprehend it in my head, I would be thankful for any kind of hint/answer. Thanks!

Comment: Try proving by induction that $f(n)\leq c(4^n-2^n)$ for some large enough constant $c$.

Comment: @Tassle What about the lower bound? is it also bigger than $c_1 (4^n - 2^n)$ how did you get to $2^n$ ? Thanks!

Comment: The lower bound is easier, you can simply use $f(n)\geq 4f(n-1)$ to show that $f(n)\in \Omega(4^n)$. Together with the upper bound this gives $f(n)\in \Theta(4^n)$. As for the $2^n$, it is just a number I picked which makes the inductive proof work out, but you could choose something else. Try showing $f(n) \leq c4^n$ directly by induction, you'll likely run into some trouble. Sometimes, trying to show something stronger actually makes the proof easier, which is the case here.

Comment: @Tassle thanks. I have another question, will the akrabazzi method work here? Cant we use the iteration method alongside with akra bazzi and say that it is $4^n$ plus <akrabazzi answer> which would be smaller? And a little question; does the akra bazzi needs finite amount of $af(n/b)$ or it can be a sum that depends of your "$n$" such as $ \sum_{l=1}^{n} af(n/b)$ <-- can you use akrabazzi if there is a sum like this?

Comment: You can't decompose into $4^n$ + <other method> because the other $f(n)$'s which appear are not independent, the $4^n$ is also part of their recursive definition. Maybe there is a way to make the Akra-Bazzi method work by some change of domain but I don't see it.  As for the number of terms in the recursive definition, they do need to be fixed in the Akra-Bazzi method, but I'm not positive it couldn't be generalized for case like the one you mention. I don't know :)